# Converting objects and finding field value difference with mongodb aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am currently developing an application in node.js + express + mongodb.
I am facing a problem that cannot be resolved. I'm desperate.

I have several objects:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Helicopter",
    "data": {
        "price": {
            "last": 65500.61
        }
    }
  },

  {
    "name": "Car",
    "data": {
        "price": {
            "last":  5850.52
        }
    }
  },
  
  {
    "name": "Truck",
    "data": {
        "price": {
            "last": 1250.49
        }
    }
  }
]
```

I want to convert this data to a new array using the aggregation framework in mobgodb. It is necessary to create a new array, where each object will contain the original objects and a new field: "difference". It will store the value of the "last" price difference.
This is the data result I want to get from mongodb:

```
[
  {
        "name": "Helicopter",
        "data": {
            "price": {
                "last": 65500.61
            }
        },
        "name": "Car",
        "data": {
            "price": {
                "last":  5850.52
            },
        },
        "difference": 59650.09
  },

  {
        "name": "Car",
        "data": {
            "price": {
                "last": 5850.52
            }
        },
        "name": "Truck",
        "data": {
            "price": {
                "last":  1250.49
            },
        },
        "difference": 4600
   },

   {
        "name": "Truck",
        "data": {
            "price": {
                "last": 1250.49
            }
        },
        "name": "Helicopter",
        "data": {
            "price": {
                "last":  65500.61
            },
        },
        "difference": -64250.12
    },

    {
        "name": "Car",
        "data": {
            "price": {
                "last": 5850.52
            }
        },
        "name": "Helicopter",
        "data": {
            "price": {
                "last":  65500.61
            },
        },
        "difference": -59650.09
    },
  
]
```

Any answer will be glad and grateful, I'm new to MongoDB :)

Comment: How do you order the documents? By default document are not ordered, so result would not be determined.

Comment: In any convenient way. I'm not quite sure what I did wrong?

Comment: The way to construct your query is to (1) get all the (unique) names (and their respective price), and (2) compare each name with all other names (except itself).  Aggregation  queries are written as [pipeline of stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#stages) and [aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#operator-expressions).

Comment: Not clear what you mean? You mean the order can be random? What is the the purpose of "difference". Or do you like to compare every document which each one? Why do you expect 4 output documents for 3 input documents? (You have "car - helicopter" and "helicopter - car")

Comment: I want to calculate the price difference between the objects, and return the resulting object, which will contain the objects and the difference between the prices